# Is it Illegal to buy a Lenco Bearcat?

Tags: fines

I have seen in video games and in movies where a SWAT Squad rolls up in this unbelievable but slow vehicle that looks so cool, and I later found out that it was a Lenco Ballistic Engineered Armored Response Counter Attack Truck, Or more known as a Lenco B.E.A.R.C.A.T (BEARCAT). Due to unreliable sources, I am once again asking this question. Is it illegal to buy a Lenco BEARCAT/BEAR as a civilian if I have enough money to do so or can you get fined?

Comment: https://letmegooglethat.com/?q=Can+you+buy+a+Lenco+BearCat%3F

Comment: @BlueDogRanch, actually the question is surprisingly difficult, even without taking different jurisdictions into account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The United States even allows [private ownership of tanks](https://www.wsj.com/articles/SB10001424127887324432004578302480951570270#:%7E:text=A%20tank%20in%20the%20U.S.,laws%20don%27t%20prohibit%20it.&text=Tanks%20generally%20aren%27t%20street,or%20on%20other%20private%20property.) and [howitzers](https://www.battlefieldvegas.com/m114-howitzer-155mm-howitzer/) with only fairly modest regulation, although the demand is small and some sort of license is required.

Most U.S. regulations would be at the state and local level. It is rare for state governments to place regulatory barriers on the ownership of what is basically an armored car, although detailing it in a manner that misleadingly conveys the impression that it is a law enforcement vehicle is usually prohibited. Security companies handling deliveries of cash and executive transportation services currently use equivalent vehicles on a regular basis.

Some armaments might be regulated at a local, state or federal level in the U.S., to the same extent that they would be if they were freestanding.

Even if the company declined to sell one to you, you could probably buy one in an auction of police department or military equipment that the selling government no longer needs. Such auctions are held on a semi-regular basis.

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify the jurisdiction, so here are some general comments:

- It the vehicle "street legal" where you want to drive it?
  There are some options which could be problematic, like rams or tear gas dispensers. So it would have to be without *those* options.
- Would Lenco be willing to sell to you, even if they were allowed to do that?
  At a quick googling, they don't seem to sell to the general public.
- Are *you* licensed to drive that kind of vehicle?
  In much of Europe, a truck license would be required.